# don't read dynamic rendered element with ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

on change of spring list box I rendered list of checkboxes according to this selection, when submit the form I can't find this new rendered element by document.getElementsByName('menuIds'); I don't why?

my jsp :

```
<html>
<head>
script src="../account.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<sf:select path="userAccount.roleId" id="roleId" name="roleId"
         onchange="getPrivilages()">

 <div class="checkbox-columns" id="privillageGroup">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My java script file(account.js):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
getCheckBoxValues();    
});
function getCheckBoxValues(){
    var checkboxes=document.getElementsByName('menuIds');
     alert('length: '+checkboxes.length); // give 0???
  }

function getPrivilages() {

var val = $('#roleId').val();
$
    .ajax({
      url :"/ADVoice/superAdmin/management/getPrivilagesLandingCategorized/" + val,
      datatype : "json",
      type : "GET",
      success : function(data) {
                var newElements = '';
for (var j = 0; j <data.length; j++) {
newElements+= "<input type='checkbox' name='menuIds'/>";
}
$('#privillageGroup').html(newElements); 
},
      error : function() {
          alert("error");
      }
    });
}
```

document.getElementsByName('menuIds').lenght give me 0 ! means no elements with name "menuIds" not rendered in the dom although it is displayed in the page!.
please help me

Comment: is your data.length > 0 ? (in the success callback

Comment: datatype should be dataType

Comment: yes data.lenght > 0 and new elements displayed in the page